# Parse server : What is the best to update the local storage with the remote data

Tags: parse-platform, local-storage, parse-server

I have a use case where I have to update a class in the local storage with the changes that have been made in my parse server. I have deleted some entries in my parse server and want those to be deleted in the local storage of the app on the user device. What is the best way to handle this. For now, I

1. Unpin all the objects for that class from my local storage.
2. Try to fetch the data from my parse server and pin them to the local storage.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse pin to local datastore is not made as a framework for synching data between device and server, but rather as a way to speed up your app by providing a local version of your data, and to avoid your app becoming unusable if the device is temporarily without a data connection. Therefore, there are no streamlined ways of synching your data between the device and the backend.

You can go about this in a couple of ways. For most situations, I would say that just unpinning and refetching is the way to go. In almost all other scenarios, you end up creating your own synching service, which can quickly become quite complex.

You can, of course, keep track of all objects that have been removed or changed since last synch, and then only unpin/re-fetch those, but this gets very hard to handle for multiple users. By far, the easiest way is to unpin all and fetch all again from the server. If this means fetching a lot of objects, you might want to rethink your logic and maybe not keep that many locally pinned objects.

Comment: I see another issue if I delete all the entries in the local storage and then try to fetch and update from the server. Let's say, in my last session, I wanted to save an object entry in my class and I did not have an internet connection. So basically, I called `pinInBackground()` and `saveEventually()` when saving the new record. Now, on when initiating the application in the next session, I have the internet and I try to first flush out my local storage and then fetch the data from the server? Would my object entry made in last session be lost?

Comment: Yes, handling local deletions is another complexity. But "pin" and "saveEventually" are two different operations. saveEventually guarantees that your object is saved remotely when connection is back, even though you might also choose to unpin in the meantime. I haven't tested this myself but I'm thinking you might face race conditions between the saveEventually and the new fetch, and that the newly saved object is not also returned by the new fetch. I don't know this for certain, though.